# Создание новой БД в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Попытался вызвать `CREATE DATABASE` в Oracle и он меня послал:

> Error report - ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed ORA-01100: database
>   already mounted

Хотя в MS SQL это прокатывало. Полез гуглить и наткнулся [на документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create003.htm#ADMIN11078).

Я правильно понимаю, что в Oracle на каждую БД нужно создавать свой экземпляр Oracle?

Немного не привычно после использования MS SQL Server, где можно много БД создавать на 1 экземпляр.

Comment: Считайте, что в терминах Оракл база данных - это схема.

Comment: Для понимания: машина -1:n -> инстанция (экземпляр) БД <- n:1->  сама БД - 1:n -> схема (юзер).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для целей логического разделения в Oracle служат "схемы" (фактически пользователи-владельцы). Для физического разделения служат табличные пространства. При этом логическое и физическое разделения действуют независимо, вы можете хранить все схемы в одном наборе файлов, а можете и одну разбить на несколько (например вынести архивные таблицы на боле медленные носители или отделить индексы от данных). При этом потребности создавать второй экземпляр на одной и той же машине обычно не возникает.

Для каждого независимого проекта, если вы хотите отделить все его объекты, вместо create database выполняйте create user.

Comment: "При этом потребности создавать второй экземпляр на одной и той же машине обычно не возникает" - конечно зависит от сложности задачи, но обычно возникает.

Answer (score 7):

> Я правильно понимаю, что в Oracle на каждую БД нужно создавать свой экземпляр Oracle?

Не правильно. На машине может существовать несколько экземпляров Oracle, каждый из которых уникально определяется парой: `ORACLE_HOME` и `ORACLE_SID`. В определённый промежуток времени один экземпляр может работать только с одной БД, которых  может быть сколько угодно.

> ORA-01100: database already mounted

Экземпляр уже смонтировал одну БД. Для создания новой выполните в командной строке:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

В sqlplus:

```
SQL> select name, open_mode from v$database;

NAME      OPEN_MODE
--------- --------------------
MYDB      READ WRITE

SQL> shutdown immediate;

SQL> startup nomount;

SQL>  select name, open_mode from v$database;

ORA-01507: database not mounted
```

Теперь можете создавать новую БД.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. База упала и не встала

Answer (score 4):

В качестве дополнения к уже данным ответам стоит упомянуть об относительно новом (доступно, начиная с Oracle 12.1.0.1) виде БД - [Pluggable DB (PDB)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234).

Т.е. в одном экземпляре БД (CDB - Container DB) может существовать много "pluggable" БД, которые будучи практически независимыми друг от друга совместно и экономно используют общие ресурсы - память, фоновые процессы и т.д. Такие "pluggable" DB можно легко переносить между разными CDB. Кроме того это сильно упрощает задачи администрирования.